# Adding waterfall to existing Pond and convert to pondless

Tags: pond

[image]We have an existing pond which has a cinder block wall above/behind it. with large rocks around the edge. It had no pond liner and no proper drainage.  I had set it up pondless i was thinking of trying to add a water fall or 2 but I had a pond guy come and say I would need to remove all the rocks and line with pond liner.

My question is : Is it possible to waterproof the cinder block without removing the rocks ? Is it feasible to build a waterfall feature here and have it go into the pond(less). Once built ?  I have been wrestling with this pond for years. I gave up trying to make pond work as we have too many trees.[image]

The first picture is the detailed area where I would try to get a waterfall built.
You can see the cinder block. behind the boulder. The pond itself is cement. But they must have added the wall later with cinder block so its not connected, hence there it probably would leak water without some liner or waterproofing.  If its not feasible to put a waterfall, I'll just put the fountain in the pondless and  give up on that.
Any other ideas for pondless setup ?  I guess a fountain is good enough and I maybe overly ambitious.

The second is the overall pond

Comment: a tall slab of rock... with a groove can support a hidden pipe for pumping

Answer (score 1):

Water is super tricky and will overflow the edges at the least opportunity.  The site will let a lot of leaves and tree stuff as they are so close.

I recommend doing it the right way

- pick a place in full sun
- dig the pond out allowing lots of shallow water areas for plants
- then use a pond liner
- then add decorative rocks

Cinder blocks can only be used outside the liner to support it.